# Django saving, deleting and viewing user uploaded media with same name

Tags: django, image, model

I have a profile app, where users can upload a profile picture. I save the picture with the user's username eg. ifakih.jpg. If that file already exists, and they want to change their profile picture, I delete the old one and replace it with the new one. I can see the change in my directory. The old ifakih.jpg is replaced with the new one. However, my website still uses the old image. If I go to the admin and check the imagefield for that user, it points to the correct directory and image, but the content is wrong.

**Models.py**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
    profilePic = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to= path_and_rename)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True)
    streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Profile)
def post_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
"""
Deleting the specific image of a Post after delete it
"""
   if instance.profilePic:
       if os.path.isfile(instance.profilePic.path):
          os.remove(instance.profilePic.path)

 @receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
 def post_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  """
  Replacing the specific image of a Post after update
  """
  if not instance.pk:
     return False

  if sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).profilePic:
      old_image = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).profilePic
      new_image = instance.profilePic
      if not old_image == new_image:
          if os.path.isfile(old_image.path):
              os.remove(old_image.path)
  else:
     return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that comes from the browser caching images.

To see whether it is related to that, try reloading with STRG + F5 to ignore cached files (you can disable the browser cache in the network tab).

You could solve that problem in two ways:

1) You disable caching for your profile pictures so that the browser always loads the image and does not cache at all. This leads to more traffic on your server and also a longer load time of your site. (NOT recommended)

2)You change the file saving behaviour and allow different filenames. This way the browser will load the image for the first request and then can use it's cache. An ImageField will also generate you a unique name while saving. (Preferred)